# What is the best way to apply for a Job as a Smart Contract engineer?

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract

So i have a question to ask. I have been a software Engineer / Software developer for several years (10+ years).
Now the market is saturated, not that i am leaving Web development 100% I want to venture into Solidity Smart contracts and become a Smart contract engineer.

I have written a BEP-20 token on Binance Smart chain using the Remix IDE. Do I still need to learn how to use truffle? What are the major things to learn to become a Solidity smart Contract Engineer?

More guides would be needed on this Please. Can I also demonstrate with previous tokens I have written both on testnet as well as on live servers?

Comment: Why do you say the software engineer / software developer market is saturated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn the newer development framework foundry because it has much more advanced  testing capabilities and all of the top teams use it. Almost no projects use truffle.

Learning how to write an ERC20 token is a good place to start, however you also should do a deep dive into protocols like Maker, Compound, Aave, Curve, and Uniswap so you have a good understanding of the core DeFi primitives and governance tooling such as DAO's, multisigs and timelocks. Then you can look into protocols that live on top of these primitives such as 1inch, balancer, yearn which show how composability unlocks new use cases and protocols.

Read up on the other popular standards such as ERC165, ERC721, ERC4626 and ERC1155.

Run through crypto zombies and ethernaut so you have a good understanding of the language and common security pitfalls. Read the consensys smart contract security docs.

While you're doing this, go to meetups where you'll meet people in the industry. With this knowledge, you'll be a very qualified candidate.

Comment: But I can use the Remix IDE too to build and deploy contracts on Binance smart Chain , not so? And its good to have it as the "IDE" used to seek a Job right?